# How to use Django (django-mentions)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Has anyone succesfully used the django-mentions lib - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mentions. If so can you help me with the issue below (thanks).  I followed the documentation (but it looks like I'm not doing it right). I am getting this error message urlize_mentions in my template

```
 TemplateSyntaxError at /
    Invalid filter: 'urlize_mentions'
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
    Django Version: 1.6.6
    Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
    Exception Value:    
    Invalid filter: 'urlize_mentions'
```

Here are the steps I followed

Step 1. pip install django-mentions

Step 2. Add 'mentions' in the INSTALLED_APPS in the settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'mentions',
    ...

)
```

Step 3. Add mentions to the url patterns

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^mentions/', include('mentions.urls')),
    ...

)
```

Step 4. Implement a mention provider, I created a mentionsprovider.py in my app

```
from mentions.mentions import Provider
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    #Implement provider
    class UserProvider(Provider):
        model = User
        def get_title(self, obj):
            return obj.username
        def search(self, request, term):
            return self.get_queryset().filter(username__istartswith=term)
```

Step 5. Add this mentions provider in the settings.py

```
 MENTIONS_PROVIDERS = {
        # You can put your provider anywhere you want
        'default': [
            'appname.mentionsprovider.UserProvider'
        ]
    }
```

Step 6. Use mentions.forms.MentionTextArea. I did this in my app's forms.py

```
from mentions.forms import MentionTextarea


class NoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        widgets = {
            'text': MentionTextarea
        }
```

In my template I have something like this (i tried various combinations)

```
{{form.note|urlize_mentions}}
{{form.text|urlize_mentions}}
{{note.text|urlize_mentions}}
```

Comment: I believe it is a bug or lack of documentation. It doesnt seem like `url_mentions` is setup as a template tag. You can create your own template tag, and call `urlize_mentions` from django mentions to serve your purpose.

Comment: I did this, created a templatetag, I didn't get the error but I could not get the mention working. Possibly a logic issue.

Comment: I'll try to put up a gist sometime soon.  (in a day or so)

Comment: Ok thanks. Looking forward to it.

Comment: any luck? it isn´t working for me...